# Bitcoin Core not updating to latest block

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have Bitcoin Core 24.0.1 64bit on Windows 10 which is seemingly stuck on updating with the latest transactions. It seems also that I have port 8333 blocked (checked on https://canyouseeme.org/), but not sure if that's even relevant. I am receiving "outbound" traffic in the peers-view window. I tried chaging the port to 8332, 80 and other random ports in the bitcoin.conf file but to no avail. I also tried deleting the peers.dat file but also without any impact. This used to work last year, I would appreciate any info on how I can get this updated so I can transfer by BTC.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEztj.png]

Comment: How long has it been like this?

Comment: Where did you download Bitcoin Core?

Comment: @PieterWuille - like this since November, like in the screenshot. I didn't notice until recently. I have the app open on WIndows startup

Comment: @Murch I just updated to the newest version to see if that would help, I got the updated .exe file from https://bitcoincore.org/

Answer (score 1):

Can you check to see if 8333 is being used by bitcoin core?   Do a netstat -ab.   Have you checked for adequate diskspace?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Disk space is not an issue, the disk that Bitcoin core is writing to has over 120GB of free space left. Upon inspecting the netstat result, bitcoin-qt.exe is connecting to ports 80, 8334, 61472, 61473, 61474, 61475 initially but later it does establish connections to concrete IPs with ports 18333 and 8333

Answer (score 0):

I suggest publishing debug logs for inspection. Additionaly, there may any of the options fix an issue:

- `-reindex` (rebuild chain state and block index from the blk*.dat files on disk)
- `-datadir=<dir>` (specify another data directory),
- `-loadblock=<file>` (Imports blocks from external file on startup).

There is the information invoked like this: `.\bitcoin-qt.exe --help`

Answer (score 0):

An outbound-only node is more than enough to sync a node. No need to fiddle with that.

There are two steps to rebuild your chain. First, you need to sync with other nodes to get the latest header. Then, bitcoin-core reads all your local *.blk blocks and rebuilds its database.

You seem to be stuck at first stage and unable to sync with other nodes. I'd suggest to check on any firewalls or other network configuration that might block this process, as well as reverting to defaults on bitcoin-core, regarding network configuration.

**You can have port 8333 closed** (or any other inbound port for that matter) **and won't have any issues while syncing.**